# How to remove the 2px artifacts on the right margin?

Tags: android, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I'm only seeing the problem on Android Chrome small screens (Nexus 5x, Nexus 6) with Android 5+. I cannot duplicate the problem on a Nexus 4. I have a basic bootstrap setup and I'm also using angular, not sure if that is related.

I'm currently getting some artifacts up to 2px wide, on the right side of the screen. They appear to be related to existing content and are directly right of some items. I tried a custom theme as well as the default and both have the same behavior.

I do NOT see this behavior on large screen Android Chrome (Nexus 9) or on desktop.

[Darker Bootstrap Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLuE2.png)

[Default Bootstrap Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJzh1.png)

Comment: Maybe the screenSize is not normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in the current version of Chrome and it should be fixed in the next version.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=549903